# getting "grep: write error: pipe broken" when command executed through application installation

Tags: shell, rhel, rhel7, rhel8

Below is the command which is executed when I install the application(this line written in one of the script of our application).
PASS=`strings /dev/urandom | grep -o '[[:alnum:]]' | head -n 10 | tr -d '\n'`

every time I get the error "grep: write error: pipe broken".

here are few points to be noted

1. When I install the application on RHEL 7.X. It runs without an issue.
2. When I run the command directory on RHEL 8.X. it doesn't give an error.
3. It throws an error only when installing the application on RHEL 8.x.

Also, I have tried few other ways to generate alphanumaric character like:

1. X=`strings /dev/urandom | grep -o -m15 '[[:alnum:]]'`
   PASS=`echo "$X" | head -n 10 | tr -d '\n'`
2. PASS=`strings /dev/urandom | tr -dc A-Za-z0-9 | head -c10`
3. PASS=`cat /dev/urandom | tr -dc A-Za-z0-9 | head -c10`
4. X=`strings /dev/urandom | head -n 100`
   PASS=`echo "X" | grep -o '[[:alnum:]]' | head -n 10 | tr -d '\n'`
5. PASS=`< /dev/urandom tr -dc '[[:alnum:]]' | head -c10`

None of this worked on RHEL 8.X while installing application. However all this command works fine when executing directly on terminal.

Comment: How did you get the impression that command _5._ didn't work?

Comment: there is some correction: after adding /dev/null only it worked. without adding it, It was giving "tr : write error : pipe broken"

Comment: The _write error_ is actually not an error which would stop command _3._ or _5._ from working, but may be interpreted as such by a program (or a person) which examines STDERR.

Comment: shubham : Since `head` exits after having read 10 lines, you certainly do have a broken pipe, if `grep` writes more than 10 lines. It wants to output more, but nobody is here anymore to get it.  Are you really worried about the fact that the pipe is broken, or are you only annoyed by seeing the  warning message?

Comment: @shubham : Plus, don't forget that the error message is also influenced by buffering/timing. `head` and `grep` run in parrallel. If `grep` finishes writing to the pipe because `head` consumes its part and terminates. you don't have a broken-pipe anymore.

Answer (score 1):

The command

```
PASS=`strings /dev/urandom | grep -o '[[:alnum:]]' | head -n 10 | tr -d '\n'`
```

does not work due to a bug in `strings`. `head` exits after having read 10 lines; `grep` detects that the other end of its output pipe has been closed, issues `grep: write error: Broken pipe` and also exits; `strings` ignores that the other end of its output pipe has been closed and blindly continues endlessly.

The commands *3.* and *5.* which don't use `strings` correctly generate a 10 character password, although *3.* also issues `write error: Broken pipe`.

Comment: this bug exists only in RHEL 8.x?

Comment: Oh okay. I was asking this because it is working fine on RHEL 7.X.

Comment: Presumably this bug exists everywhere, but whether it shows up depends on the disposition of the SIGPIPE signal. If SIGPIPE was set to ignore by the process that invoked the current shell, the bug can be observed; if SIGPIPE is not ignored, its default behavior is to terminate the process. I could see one and the other behavior on two different Ubuntu 20.04.2 LTS systems.